# how to affect audio context for a specific howler.js sound

Tags: javascript, volume, fade, audiocontext, howler.js

I'm trying to insert some audio context effects into specific howler sounds including doing my own fade in and out. (I know howler has a fade feature, however I need to do my own).  I know how to fade the global howler that affects all sounds, however I'm not understanding how to affect a specific howl object I've created - in the case of this example, we'll call the specific howl object 'test'

```
    var test = new Howl ({
                src: ['url'],
        });
```

This has been tested and works for doing my own fade on the global howler:

```
  Howler.masterGain.gain.setValueAtTime(1, Howler.ctx.currentTime);
  Howler.masterGain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, Howler.ctx.currentTime + 10);
```

However for a howl object called 'test', I'm unclear how I would do the same fade out to only that howler object?

After reviewing the howler.js code, I've tried the following that all error in different ways:

```
  test.masterGain.gain.setValueAtTime(1, Howler.ctx.currentTime);
  test.masterGain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, Howler.ctx.currentTime + 10);

  test.gain.setValueAtTime(1, Howler.ctx.currentTime);
  test.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, Howler.ctx.currentTime + 10);

  test._node.gain.setValueAtTime(1, Howler.ctx.currentTime);
  test._node.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, Howler.ctx.currentTime + 10);
```

Please forgive my misunderstanding of how howler works with sounds, JS, and audio context in general.  I'm not an expert, but am trying.  I'm sure that this is not how to access the object 'test' and do a fade on it.  Note that I'd still like to use howler to define 'test' including loading the sound, playback, pause, etc.  I'm trying to stay away from raw coding audio context for 'test' from scratch.  For now, I only need to directly access the volume for 'test' using the audio context.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the way to do this is a bit tricky, since you'll have to tamper with private properties, but I think this shouldn't be much of a problem since what you want to do (fade in/out) is simple enough.

```js
// Getting a ref to the sound object
const sound = Howl._sounds[0];

// Get gain node
const gainNode = sound._node;

// Fade out
gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(1, Howler.ctx.currentTime);
gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, Howler.ctx.currentTime + 10);
```

It's honestly that simple. Now the *fun* part is doing slightly more complicated tricks like connecting the gain to another audio context. This can be done by disconnecting the gain node from the master gain node.

```js
gainNode.disconnect(Howler.masterGain);

// Now connect to another gain node connected to another audio context
gainNode.connect(anotherGainNode);
```

This should be enough for you to be able to achieve what you want/need

Comment: Thanks very much!  One question about getting the reference that I'm not clear on.  How would it relate to my example where I had a howl called 'test'.  Is [0] only the first defined sound?  If I had multiple sounds, would that be [1], [2], [3], etc.?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but yes, so [0] would be your first and only sound if you aren't using an audiosprite

Comment: When you use audio sprites, the following sounds would be the other sections of the audio sprite, but I can confirm this. Just console.log your howl and see what's inside

Comment: Great.  I won't be using sprites but I will have a lot of other separate Howl sound objects.  Is there some way I can get the connection between Howl._sounds[0] and a sound object like 'test'?  I won't know which is [0], which is [1], etc.  I'm defining each sound like... 
    var test = new Howl ({
                src: ['url'],
        });

Thanks again - this is helping very much.

Comment: @briandm each sound has a name property. I don't know what the default is, but each sound has a name prop. You shouldn't be too worried about the name props unless you use audio sprites. Also make sure you are using web audio with howler, it won't work without that